# Regex não funciona no chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Tenho o seguinte script no qual uso um jquery para validar uma expressão regular que filtre os nomes dos arquivos para upload:

```
$(document).on('change', "input[type='file']", function() {
         var validaFile = $("input[type='file']").val();

        if (validaFile != '') {
            var regex = RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$');

            if (!regex.test(validaFile)) {
                $("input[type='file']").val('');
                alert("O nome deste arquivo é inválido. Por favor renomeie o arquivo.");
                return;
            } 
        }
    });
```

A questão é que o código funcionou co Firefox Developer, mas não funciona no chrome e Edge. Independente do arquivo que eu insira sempre dará nome de arquivo inválido.

Comment: O que esse regex deveria fazer?

Comment: Tenho um input no meu site para upload de arquivos. Esse regex não faz tratamento do tipo do arquivo, apenas do nome. Exemplo: se o usuario tentar inserir um arquivo com o nome Me,u!Arqu;ivo vai ser um arquivo de nome invalido e não podera ser anexado. Apenas serão anexados arquivo com caracteres az Az _ -.

Comment: Estranho.. eu testei aqui e funcionou. http://jsfiddle.net/yj78v/57/

Comment: Teste um arquivo Exemplo: Teste.txt e um T,es!te.txt ... Ira retornar a mesma mensagem

Comment: @PauloHDSousa o questionamento dele são os arquivos corretos que estão entrando no If.

Comment: Correto, no firefox dev dá tudo certo .. se eu insiro um arquivo com nome invalido ele não me permite, e se coloco um com nome valido ele permite. O problema é que no chrome não funciona e mesmo que eu tente colocar um arquivo valido, ele diz que é invalido

Comment: Por que `new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$');` ao invés de `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$/`? Outra coisa tem um hifen sobrendo após o 9, você tem que escapar este hifen assim: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_.]+$/` ou melhor `/^[\w\d\-_.]+$/`

Comment: Obrigado pela dica cara, mas com a resposta de baixo o problema já foi resolvido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o Chrome adiciona `C:\fakepath\` antes do nome do arquivo.

Uma solução que funciona em ambos navegadores é acessar diretamente a propriedade [`files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FileList) do input:

```js
$(document).on('change', "input[type='file']", function() {
  // acessa diretamente o objeto do input
  var validaFile = $(this)[0].files[0].name;

  if (validaFile != '') {
    var regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+$');

    if (!regex.test(validaFile)) {
      $("input[type='file']").val('');
      $('#msg').html("O nome deste arquivo é inválido. Por favor renomeie o arquivo.");
      return;
    } else {
      $('#msg').html('O nome do arquivo é válido!');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" />
<br /><span id="msg"></span>
```

[Mais detalhes sobre a interface `File`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/File)

Comment: +1 muito bom não sabia que era por causa disso.

Comment: Correto cara, funcionou mesmo. Também não sabia disso, muito obrigado.